# How to swap column values to be column name

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have created a minimal example to demonstrate my problem.

I have a data frame and I want to swap the columns to be based on the values within the columns. In other words I want to convert something like this:

```
structure(list(index = c("a", "b", "c"), A = c("zz", "yy", "xx"), B = c("yy", NA, "vv"), C = c("xx", "ww", "vv")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("index", "A", "B", "C"))
```

into a data frame that is something like this:

```
structure(list(index = c("a", "b", "c", "c"), vv = c(NA, NA, "B", "C"), ww = c(NA, "C", NA, NA), xx = c("C", NA, "A", NA),     yy = c("B", "A", NA, NA), zz = c("A", NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("index", "vv", "ww", "xx", "yy", "zz"))
```

UPDATE

Although at least one solution worked for my minimal example, it appears not to work for my main application. Posted below is a snippet of my actual df.

```
structure(list(index = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("16fA", "16fB", "16gA", "16gB", "16gC", "16gD", "16gE", "16gF", "16gG", "16gP"), class = "factor"), AA = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "GEC (1)", class = "factor"),     BB = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "BER (3)", class ="factor"), 
CC = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "ZUR (3)", class = "factor"),     DD = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA,     NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("LIK (3)",     "SLB (3)"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("index", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with `melt/dcast` from `reshape2` (or the same functions in `data.table`)

```
library(reshape2)
#convert the dataset to long format
d2 <- melt(d1, id.var='index', na.rm=TRUE)
#create a sequence column grouped by value, index
d2$i1 <- with(d2, ave(seq_along(index), value, index,FUN=seq_along))
#convert from long to wide format
dcast(d2, i1+index~value, value.var='variable')[-1]
#  index   vv   ww   xx   yy   zz
#1    a <NA> <NA>    C    B    A
#2    b <NA>    C <NA>    A <NA>
#3    c    B <NA>    A <NA> <NA>
#4    c    C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

---

If we need to do with `dplyr/tidyr`, use `gather/spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(d1, variable, value, -index, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
           group_by(value, index) %>%                
           mutate(i1= row_number()) %>%
           spread(value, variable) %>%
           select(-i1)
#  index    vv    ww    xx    yy    zz
#   (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
# 1     a    NA    NA     C     B     A
# 2     b    NA     C    NA     A    NA
# 3     c     B    NA     A    NA    NA
# 4     c     C    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

---

Based on the updated dataset, the `dcast` output is

```
dcast(d2, i1+index~value, value.var='variable')[-1]
#    index BER (3) GEC (1) LIK (3) SLB (3) ZUR (3)
#1   16fA    <NA>      AA    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#2   16fB    <NA>      AA    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#3   16gA    <NA>      AA    <NA>      DD      CC
#4   16gB    <NA>      AA    <NA>      DD      CC
#5   16gC      BB      AA    <NA>      DD    <NA>
#6   16gD    <NA>      AA    <NA>      DD    <NA>
#7   16gE    <NA>      AA    <NA>      DD    <NA>
#8   16gF    <NA>      AA    <NA>      DD      CC
#9   16gG      BB      AA    <NA>      DD    <NA>
#10  16gP      BB      AA      DD    <NA>    <NA>
```

and the `gather/spread` output is

```
#     index BER (3) GEC (1) LIK (3) SLB (3) ZUR (3)
#   (fctr)   (chr)   (chr)   (chr)   (chr)   (chr)
#1    16fA      NA      AA      NA      NA      NA
#2    16fB      NA      AA      NA      NA      NA
#3    16gA      NA      AA      NA      DD      CC
#4    16gB      NA      AA      NA      DD      CC
#5    16gC      BB      AA      NA      DD      NA
#6    16gD      NA      AA      NA      DD      NA
#7    16gE      NA      AA      NA      DD      NA
#8    16gF      NA      AA      NA      DD      CC
#9    16gG      BB      AA      NA      DD      NA
#10   16gP      BB      AA      DD      NA      NA
```

Comment: @Geoff Try `ave(seq_along(index),...` instead of `ave(index,..` (updated the code).  It works now.  The columns in the new dataset are `factor`.  So, using that `ave(index,..` created only NA values.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you starting dataframe is called `d1`, you could use a combine `melt` & `dcast` operation with the *data.table* package:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(d1), "index"),
      index ~ value,
      value.var = "variable",
      fun.aggregate = toString,
      fill = NA_character_)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE))),
                          by = index][, "NA" := NULL]
```

which gives:

```
   index vv ww xx yy zz
1:     a NA NA  C  B  A
2:     b NA  C NA  A NA
3:     c  B NA  A NA NA
4:     c  C NA  A NA NA
```

---

With the new dataset you could do:

```
df2 <- dcast(melt(setDT(df1), "index"),
             index ~ value,
             value.var = "variable",
             fun.aggregate = toString,
             fill = NA_character_)[, "NA" := NULL]
```

which gives:

```
> df2
    index BER (3) GEC (1) LIK (3) SLB (3) ZUR (3)
 1:  16fA      NA      AA      NA      NA      NA
 2:  16fB      NA      AA      NA      NA      NA
 3:  16gA      NA      AA      NA      DD      CC
 4:  16gB      NA      AA      NA      DD      CC
 5:  16gC      BB      AA      NA      DD      NA
 6:  16gD      NA      AA      NA      DD      NA
 7:  16gE      NA      AA      NA      DD      NA
 8:  16gF      NA      AA      NA      DD      CC
 9:  16gG      BB      AA      NA      DD      NA
10:  16gP      BB      AA      DD      NA      NA
```